# Building strongSwan from source

Tags: ubuntu, services, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I'm having huge trouble with getting strongswan to work. I'd like to try the newest version and customize it with plugins. I'm following the instruction available here: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/InstallationDocumentation

```
connecting to 'unix:///var/run/charon.vici' failed: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm on Ubuntu if that helps.

EDIT: actually, this is the right way to configure strongswan, for anyone wondering:

```
    ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-curve25519 --enable-systemd --enable-swanctl --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-systemduserunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd
```

Comment: `make install` will install the software but won't attempt to start any of the daemons. Did you use `configure ... --enable-systemd`?

Comment: Yes I did, I got an error: checking for systemd system unit directory... configure: error: not found (try --with-systemdsystemunitdir)

Comment: @roaima sorry for not asking the question properly, you have actually helped tremendously and the service is starting. Thank you, turns out your mind-reading is quite good today :)